# VBA - Combobox - AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have the code below for my combo box (ActiveX) to filter the data in a table based on the value.

The code executes fine and filters the table, however then crashes with the autofilter method of range class failed error

I don't really understand why?

The combo box is an ActiveX combo box and links to cell F5, the list range is a dynamic range that changes depending on what is in the table

Code:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If Range("F5").Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter

Else

With ActiveSheet

.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
 Criteria1:=Range("F5").Value

End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to find the real cause of this error, because `on error resume next` is just a way to ignore errors, not avoid them. (1) Could indicate what the range is of *Table3*, e.g. `A2:C1000`. (2) Is the combo box on the same sheet as *Table3*?

Comment: The combo box is in Cell F5 and the list Object is on the same sheet in cells C8:H152.

Comment: C8:H152 does not include F5...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
with activesheet
    If .Range("F5").Value = "" Then
        .ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter

    Else
        .ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
 Criteria1:=Range("F5").Value
    end if  

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this - no different unfortunately

Comment: maybe  the F5 cell is on the same row as your listobject

Comment: No, the list object is on row 8

Answer (score 0):

Figured a solution:

Not sure what was causing it exactly but I just put an on error resume next in:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

With ActiveSheet

If Range("F5").Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter

 Else
 On Error Resume Next
 .ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
 Criteria1:=Range("F5").Value

End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I doubt this is a solution, because if you ignore the error, the statement will in fact not have executed. Does your list now get limited to the value you select in the combo box?

Comment: Yeah the table filters to whatever value is in the combo box and if I clear the combo box, the filter clears. 
So it appears to work as intended...